# Deep copy of an ArrayList <Integer>

Tags: arraylist, deep-copy

I'd like to copy the ArrayList  zf into the ArrayList  copyzf. The copy has to be a deep one.

I already tried:

```html
public class ZFW {
  Integer zfw;
 public ZFW copy() {
  ZFW m= new ZFW();
  m.zfw=this.zfw.copy();
  return m;
 }
}
```

and in the executing code:

```html
 for(int r=0; r<zf.size();r++) {
    Integer z;
    z=zf.get(r);
    copyzf.set(r, z.copy());
   }
```

The error "The method copy() is undefined for the type Integer" occurs. I can't change the data type of the ArrayLists, does anybody know how I can solve the Problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post the tag properly for example in which language you have written your code, also please post the full error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers are immutable, so a deep copy is useless. Where in your code is the mentioned `ArrayList`?